# NGINX proxy not serving static content

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, website, static-content

I've setup a proxy NGINX that access a Wordpress server on 10.0.0.151:

```
#
# Default server configuration
#
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name _;

    location / {
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then
        # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {
    server_name     judith.com www.judith.com *.judith.com;
    return 301 https://www.judith.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/judith.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/judith.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    server_name     judith.com www.judith.com *.judith.com;
    
    location / {
            proxy_pass      http://10.0.0.151;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location ~ ^/(images/|img/|javascript/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|flash/|media/|static/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
        root http://10.0.0.151;
        access_log off;
        expires max;
    }

    client_max_body_size 2000M;
}
```

When going to https://www.judith.com I can access the web page, get the certification (trusted page) and show the page, *but* without all static content (images, css, etc.).

How to make it properly show all static content (js, css, images, etc)?

Sure I'm missing something simple... Help appreciated.

Comment: What does `root http://10.0.0.151;` mean? This should be a pathname to where the files are located.

Comment: Are your static files located at the `10.0.0.151` server or on the server that runs nginx?

Comment: 10.0.0.151 is the server with the static content (Wordpress). NGINX is 10.0.0.10.